# verify that string is html/xml in r

Tags: html, r, httr

I have a Response from a get request. Sometimes within the JSON response there is a html string. But there is no pattern that i would know that beforehand. How can i programmatically test whether the given string is html code?

**Reproducible example (without get request):**

```
resp <- read_html("https://www.r-bloggers.com") # not a get request but easy to reproduce
```

What i tried so far:

```
typeof(resp) # Returns "list". 
XML::isXMLString(resp) # Fails, but close to what i am Looking for
```

Comment: Maybe checking if result contains html tags `grepl("<.*>", c("<html tag>", "no html tag"))`

Comment: why not use gsub and check for patterns

Comment: You could use `HEAD` from the `httr` package

Comment: @Clemsang/@Not_Dave: Thanks I´ll go for that. Seems it is not implemented in any package so far. @Matt Great hint, thank you. It seems it does not work for the get request, but its a great function to Keep in mind!